# Given a string s and an integer i, create all contiguous substrings of s, sort & then concatenate them, and find the letter at index i efficiently

Tags: algorithm, math, combinatorics

For a given string say `dbac`, the possible substrings are [d,db,dba,dbac,b,ba,bac,a,ac,c] . Sort them and concatenate to a string: `aacbbabaccddbdbadbac`. Find the character at a given index. In this example, if we were given i=2 then we'd return 'c'. How can we do this efficiently?

Let's say there are three flavors of this question:

- The input letters are unique
- The input letters aren't unique but are treated as unique with position as a tiebreaker. E.g. for 'acab' we'd treat the first 'a' as strictly preceding the second 'a' in a sort. For this example, the expanded string would be 'aacacaacabaabbccacab'
- The input letters aren't unique and there's no tiebreaker. E.g. for 'acab' we treat the two 'a's as equivalent, so the expanded string would be 'aaabacacaacabbccacab'

For anyone who is curious, here is the O(n^3) approach coded in Java by someone else that sparked this question:

```java
public char solve(String s, int m) {
    int n = s.length();
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for(int j=i+1; j<=n; j++) {
            list.add(s.substring(i,j));
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(list);
    for(String s1 : list) {
        int q = s1.length();
        if(m >=q) m -=q;
        else {
            return s1.charAt(m);
        }
    }
    return ' ';
}
```

Comment: Before expecting answers, can you put what your thoughts about how this can be done efficiently [in your post](/help/how-to-ask)?  Right now your post is basically identical to a new user going "how do I X?" without code or signs of having worked through the question, with an answer post that [isn't an  answer, they're post details](/help/how-to-answer). So move that answer into your post so that others can see what you've been considering and trying already.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I don't understand your concern. My answer is an answer, not part of the question or post details. This is supported by s/o: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer. "Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged users to answer their own questions."

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I don't think it helps anyone for me to post the O(n^3) solution someone else wrote elsewhere that motivated this.

Comment: I most certainly would, because posts should stand on their own: if you have a question after finding someone talking about an algorithm and gave it your own shot, [include the code/a description of what sparked your question](/help/how-to-ask). And then your own analysis still goes in the question post, because it's your best understanding and you're asking where it's not good enough (yet).

Comment: To satisfy anyone's curiosity, I posted the O(n^3) approach that sparked the question.

Comment: Cheers, but as a [Stackoverflow post](/help/on-topic) you _really_ need to edit your attempt into your post, too. You have enough rep to know what [good questions look like](/help/how-to-ask). If you have a question, put the details for that question in your post. Don't split them into a post and an answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255394/discussion-between-dave-and-mike-pomax-kamermans).

Comment: _the possible substrings are [d,db,dba,dbac,b,ba,bac,a,ac]_ Why isn't "c" a possible substring?

Comment: @JohnGordon Good catch, thanks. Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a linear approach, illustrated with the example.

```
input: string = 'dbac'
       target = 2 
       length = 4
```

We'll use n for the length, so n=4 in the example

1. O(n): Associate each character with its index in the input string. If there are repeated characters, associate each character with the ordered list of its indices.

   d=>0, b=>1, a=>2, c=>3
2. O(1) Sort the characters (O(1) assumes English or some other language with a fixed character count).

   [a, b, c, d]
3. Note a couple things:

- the character at index i is the first character of substrings of length 1 up to n-i.
- the cumulative count of characters of all substrings starting at index i is 1 + 2 + ... + (n-i) = (n-i) * (n-i+1)/2

4. O(1): We'll use 'count' to store the count of cumulative characters. Initialize count=0. We'll use 'pri_count' to store the count of cumulative characters of substrings starting with the previous character. Intialize this to 0 as well.

   count = 0
   pri_count = 0
5. O(n): In sorted character order, then in sorted index order for that character, increase count appropriately. I.e., if we're considering index i then add (n-i) * (n-i+1)/2. Stop at the first character/index combo that has count-1 >= target (where target is the supplied index).

   parse 'a': index of a is 2; count += (4-2)*(4-2+1)/2 = 3
   stop because 3 > target = 2.
6. O(n): If count-1 == target then we're done and the last character of the input string is the answer.

   n/a

<for illustration, not O(n) but a faster approach is below> Otherwise, we need to know which of the substrings starting with the character in question is the answer. The concept here is that we start with pri_count and successively/cumulatively add 1, 2, ... until we meet or exceed the target. Say adding the integer r causes us to exceed the target by s (possibly 0). Then the character we want to return is r-s to the right of the character in question. Here we're referring to the input string.

```
character in question is 'a'
pri_count = 0
pri_count += 1: pri_count = 1 < target
pri_count += 2: pri_count = 3 = target + 1
So adding the integer r=2 caused us to exceed the target by s=1
So the character we want is r-s = 2-1 = 1 to the right of 'a' in the input string, which is 'c'.
```

O(n): The method I used to illustrate step 6 is potentially slow, but we can quickly solve it using the method of step 5 in reverse (i.e. solving t*(t+1)/2 = target - pri_count for t, taking t' as the floor of this, then r-s will equal target-t'.

```
t*(t+1)/2 = 3-0 = 3. Solve via quadratic formula
t = 2; t' = 2; 3-2 = 1, and again we're taking the character 1 to the right of 'a' in the input string.
```

Here's Ruby code to solve this (read as pseudocode if you don't use Ruby):

```
def f(str, m)
  n = str.length
  
  char_to_indices = Hash.new {|h, k| h[k] = []}
  
  str.split('').each_with_index do |char, i|
    char_to_indices[char].append(i)
  end
  
  sorted_chars = char_to_indices.keys.sort
  
  count = 0
  pri_count = 0
  char_index = 0
  done = false
  
  sorted_chars.each do |char|
  
    char_to_indices[char].each do |i|
      char_index = i
      pri_count = count
      count += (n-i)*(n-i+1)/2
      done = true if count-1 >= m
      break if done
    end
    break if done
  end
  
  if count-1 == m
    return str[-1]
  else
    # solve t*(t+1)/2 = m - pri_count
    # t**2 + t + 2*(pri_count - m) = 0
    
    t = ((-1 + (1 + 8*(m-pri_count))**0.5)/2.0).floor
    shift = m - pri_count - (t * (t+1)/2)
    return str[char_index + shift]
  end
end
```

Here are results for the short example:

```
> f('dbac',2)
=> "c"
```

TODO: This solves the first two flavors of the problem, but needs alteration to handle the third. I'll update this for that variation when I have time.

Comment: How is sorting the list of characters O(1)? i dont follow how fixed language count of  letters in it is relevant.  you have to sort just the letters that are present which means at minimum it's O(N) but i have yet to see a sort be O(N)

Comment: @UpAndAdam It's O(1) because the size of the input is O(1).

Comment: @UpAndAdam To elaborate on that, in step 1 we do the linear work of bucketing into characters (so 26 for English). As n grows to infinity, the number of characters is capped at 26. When we do the sort, it'll use a standard algorithm, say merge sort, but the time that sort takes isn't affected by n because it always sorts at most 26 things. It's O(1) because it doesn't grow (past a very small size) with the input.

Comment: where does it say letters cant repeat? in his example there are repeats.   That the letters come from a finite set doesn't change this to constant time, its still a function of the letters actually present to sort them unless i misunderstand your algo and you are just using a vector of 26 as a hashtable and marking the count of each letter at the appropriate index. in which case you still are bound to O(n) where n is the length of the input.

Comment: ahh i see if you focus on the first of the three cases your algo holds.. my apologies i was locked into the second two, where admittedly his handling of the duplicates becomes unclear.

Comment: @UpAndAdam My solution works for the middle case as well, but completely fails to address the third/final case.